# Is there a light weight java web service framework or lib?

Tags: java, rest, service

I just want to find a light weight framework or lib based on which rest-style service can be registered. I will use tomcat or jetty as the web server.

Is there an appropriated one?

Answer (score 4):

also look at [activeweb](http://code.google.com/p/activeweb/) . It allows creating of resful controllers.
Loot at [dropwizard](http://dropwizard.codahale.com) too

Take a look at [jooby](http://jooby.org) It has a nice java8 syntax for defining routes and supports websockets too. It also has a great module system and a bunch of ready modules that range from assets preprocessing to orm integration.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps Restlet is what you are looking for. I found it's handling very easy and comfortable.

http://www.restlet.org/

Comment: Cool. I once read the document ,but didn't go further. After your suggestion, I found it's just what I am looking for.  what I need is in this page:http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/275-restlet/312-restlet.html

Answer (score 3):

Another one is  [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Play framework seems like a considerable option: www.playframework.org, I'm thinking of creating my next software project in this framework.